# How to handle variable columns rows in a fixed column table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

My table will look something like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Entry</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
    </tr>    
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Cooper</td>
        <td>Vikings</td>
        <td>Giants</td>
        <td>Rams</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jon Doe</td>
        <td>Bears</td>
        <td></td> 
        <td>Seahawks</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And my data will be something like this:

```
{
 "name" : "Cooper",
 "picks" [{"w1": "vikings"}, {"w2" : "Giants"}, {"w3" : "Rams"}]
},
{
 "name" : "Jon Doe",
 "picks" [{"w1": "Bears"}, {"w3" : "Seahawks"}]
}
```

I'm looking for advice on how to best create my output.  This is just a simple example, my real model will have 30 columns so I'll probably hide some of them depending on what week it is.  The picks will be in order but I can't be certain that all the weeks will be represented.  In my example above Jon Doe forgot to make a pick for week 2.

Thanks

Comment: Could it be possible to make the array contain `undefined` or `null`? Then a simple ng-repeat would solve your problem with some tweaks. Otherwise maybe an object instead of an array?

Comment: Yes, that was my initial thought.  Loop over the picks  and insert a dummy record for any missing picks.  I was hoping there was a clever way to avoid doing that.

Comment: Is it possible to modify the data so it looks differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution requires that your data structure switches from an array to an object containing keys for each week. It will not require you to insert a dummy record or undefined records into the array, although I don't think that solution is necessarily that bad.

The snippet below shows a directive that would solve your problem. Note that in the html for the directive (the tbody element), I've set max-columns to 3 to match your data.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("pickersCtrl", ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.data = [{
        "name": "Cooper",
        "picks": {
          "w1": "Vikings",
          "w2": "Giants",
          "w3": "Rams"
        }
      }, {
        "name": "Jon Doe",
        "picks": {
          "w1": "Bears",
          "w3": "Seahawks"
        }
      }];
    }
  ])
  .directive("pickersRepeat", [
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
          pickers: '=',
          maxColumns: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch("pickers", function(pickers) {
            if (!pickers) {
              return;
            }
            var maxColumns = +scope.maxColumns;
            for (var i = 0; i < pickers.length; i++) {
              var picker = pickers[i];
              var row = angular.element('<tr/>');
              element.append(row);
              var nameColumn = angular.element('<td/>').text(picker.name); // append user name to Entry row
              row.append(nameColumn);
              var picks = picker.picks; // get user picks
              
              for (var j = 0; j < maxColumns; j++) {
                var column = angular.element('<td/>');
                row.append(column);
                var pick = picks["w" + (j + 1)]; // since the wX seem to start with 1 instead of 0 we add 1 here
                if (pick) {
                  // user made a pick for week j
                  column.text(pick); // put the text in column j
                }
              }
            }
          });
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <table ng-controller="pickersCtrl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Entry</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody pickers-repeat pickers="data" , max-columns="3">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```